# How to represent fmethods as parameters in the sequence diagram and memory stack

Tags: stack, sequence-diagram

I have doubts about the representation of methods as parameters in the seqeunce diagram having the memory stack structure as an idea

If I have the following code:

```
Bank.charge_money(conf.get_iban(), total_amount);
transaction_succesful = 1;
```

In the sequence diagram I should represents methods calls as parameters first and then the main method.

```
--> get_iban() 
<--
--> charge_money(getIbanResult, total_amount)
```

(Might this representetion be correct?)

But in the memory stack the main method is pushed to the top of stack and then parameter methods are called later.

is it just a difference in representation?